# Validate Facebook signed_request signature in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, sha256, hmac

I'm building a Facebook Page app in Classic ASP. I've been unable to match the signature that Facebook passes into the app as the first part of the POSTed `signed_request`.

Because there are few libraries for cryptography in VBScript, I'm using server side Javascript and the crypto-js library from https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

I've tried to translate the PHP code example from Facebook's docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr into Javascript. I can generate an HMAC SHA256 hash of the `signed_request` payload but that doesn't match the `signed_request` signature.

I think the problem is that Facebook's signature is in a different format. It looks to be binary (*~1抚Ö.....*) while the HMAC SHA256 hash I'm generating is a hexadecimal string (*7f7e8f5f.....*). In Facebook's PHP example the `hash_hmac` function uses the raw binary parameter. So I think I need to either convert Facebook's signature to hexadecimal or my signature to binary in order to do an "apples-to-apples" comparison and get a match.

Here's my code:

```
/* Use the libraries from https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/
crypto-js/crypto-js.min.js
crypto-js/hmac-sha256.min.js
crypto-js/enc-base64.min.js
*/

var signedRequest = Request.queryString("signed_request")

var FB_APP_SECRET = "459f038.....";

var arSR = signedRequest.split(".");
var encodedSig = arSR[0];
var encodedPayload = arSR[1];

var payload = base64UrlDecode(encodedPayload);
var sig = base64UrlDecode(encodedSig);

var expectedSig;

expectedSig = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedPayload, FB_APP_SECRET); // Unaltered payload string; no match
expectedSig = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(payload, FB_APP_SECRET); // base64-decoded payload string; no match

if (sig == expectedSig) {
    Response.write(payload);
} else {
    Response.write("Bad signature");
}

function base64UrlDecode(input) {
    // Replace characters and convert from base64.
    return Base64.decode(input.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/"));
}
```

Comment: According to the crypto.js documentation, that has its own method for base64 de-/encoding - maybe try and use those, instead of `Base64.decode`? (After you done the -+ replacement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the crypto-js documentation about encoding I found the solution. The de-/encoding methods provided by crypto-js are listed under 'Encoders' at the bottom of https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/ (Thanks for the nudge, CBroe.)

The solution was to use `.toString()` on the signatures. It seems like crypto-js uses a word format that was preventing a comparison match. I did also switch to using the base64 decoding provided by crypto-js in order to stick with one library.

Here's my updated code:

```
/* Use the libraries from https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/
crypto-js/crypto-js.min.js
crypto-js/hmac-sha256.min.js
crypto-js/enc-base64.min.js
*/

var signedRequest = Request.queryString("signed_request")

var FB_APP_SECRET = "459f038.....";

var arSR = signedRequest.split(".");
var encodedSig = arSR[0];
var encodedPayload = arSR[1];

var payload = base64UrlDecode(encodedPayload);
var sig = base64UrlDecode(encodedSig);

var expectedSig = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedPayload, FB_APP_SECRET); /******** Correct payload */

if (sig.toString() != expectedSig.toString()) { /******* Use .toString() to convert to normal strings */
    Response.write(payload);
} else {
    Response.write("Bad signature");
}

function base64UrlDecode(input) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse( /******** Decode */
        input.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/") // Replace characters
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this for their required user data deletion webhook. No external dependencies needed anymore:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function parseSignedRequest(signedRequest, secret) {
  const [signatureReceived, encodedPayload] = signedRequest.split('.', 2);
  const payload = b64decode(encodedPayload)
  const data = JSON.parse(payload);

  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(payload);
  const expectedSignature = hmac.digest('base64');

  if (signatureReceived === expectedSignature) {
    return data;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Signature mismatch");
  }
}

function b64decode(data) {
  const buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
  return buff.toString('ascii');
}
```

It's a translation of [their example PHP code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/delete-data#data-deletion-request-callback). I also have [a repo setup](https://github.com/nearwood/node-fb-signedrequest) with tests.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const _atob = (str) => Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('binary')

const parseSignedRequest = (signed_request, app_secret) => { 
  const [encoded_sig, payload] = signed_request.split('.')
  const json = _atob(payload)
  const data = JSON.parse(json)

  
  if (!data.algorithm || data.algorithm.toUpperCase() !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    return {error: true, type: 'Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256'}
  }

  // check sig 
  const expected_sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.facebook.app_secret)
    .update(payload).digest('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=/g, '')

  if (encoded_sig !== expected_sig) {
    return ({error: true, type: 'invalid_signature'})
  }

  return {error: false, parsedRequest: data}
}

const {error, type, parsedRequest} = parseSignedRequest(signed_request)
```